# Converting the result from JSON GENERATE to EBCDIC

Tags: cobol

For one of my requirements I need the JSON GENERATE function in COBOL 6. My problem is, that it returns UTF-8, but I need the data in EBCDIC (CCSID 1140). Is there a way to convert this? Every solution I found uses national data types, but I have to use the NODBCS compiler option, so those don't work.

Comment: If you want to do it in COBOL, you need to use a DBCS compiler.

Comment: May I ask why you would like EBCDIC JSON? The JSON Standard states that JSON is to be represented in UTF-8, and having JSON in EBCDIC might not a good idea. Also, why can't you use NODBCS? Do you have a C++ compiler installed?

Comment: @NicoleTrudeau The Database the JSON is sent to uses EBCDIC, also the 3rd Party program I'm looking to replace creates it in EBCDIC.

Comment: @RalZarek even if the database is natively EBCDIC, you can probably still set the field up as binary data and just store the UTF-8. By making the JSON EBCDIC, you are essentially making it unreadable to anything that reads JSON until you convert it back.

Answer (score 2):

I do apologize for not first asking a question (but I am too new to StackOverflow to allow that.) The question would be "do you have C++ and can you link C++ with your COBOL?" I just tried this program:

```
#include <iconv.h>

class myConv
   {
   public:
   static myConv globalConv;
   size_t conv(char ** restrict f, unsigned int * restrict flen,
               char ** restrict t, unsigned int * restrict tlen)
      {
      if (ok_)
         {
         return iconv(cd_, f, flen, t, tlen);
         }
      else
         {
         return (size_t)-1;
         }
      }
   private:
   myConv()
      {
      cd_ = iconv_open("1047",      // EBCDID
                       "1208");     // UTF-8
      ok_ = (cd_ != (iconv_t)-1);
      // possibly indicate what the error is
      }
   ~myConv()
      {
      if (ok_)
         {
         if (iconv_close(cd_) != 0)
            {
            // possibly indicate what the error is
            }
         }
      }
   bool ok_;
   iconv_t cd_;
   };

myConv myConv::globalConv;

extern "C" bool CNV(char * f, unsigned int flen,
                    char * t, unsigned int tlen)
   {
   return myConv::globalConv.conv(&f, &flen,
                                  &t, &tlen) != (size_t)-1;
   }
```

and the COBOL call looked like this:

```
json generate result from grp
call "CNV" using by reference result,
                 by value length of result,
                 by reference convertedres,
                 by value length of convertedres,
                 returning cres
```

and cres is a PIC S9(9) COMP data item which will have a non-zero value of the conversion succeeded.

Again, I apologize for not first asking if C++ is a possibility.  (Or even C.  The code could be easily done in C.)  Also, the result is not quite perfect owing to the JSON GENERATE result being zero filled.